# Root domain in SPF record instead of full hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, email-server, spf

Can i use root domain like `google.com` instead of `_spf.google.com` in SPF record?.

**My SPF record**

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net include:_spf.google.com include:mxsmtp.sendpulse.com +a +mx ~all
```

**Can i change it to**

```
v=spf1 include:cloudflare.net include:google.com include:sendpulse.com +a +mx ~all
```

This make any problem?

Answer (score 4):

To make it more clear what is what:

- `_spf.google.com` is an arbitrarily chosen domain name that Google does not use for sending mail, but which they set up with an SPF `TXT` record in order for their mail customers to have one common place to refer to with `include:_spf.google.com` in their own SPF records.
- `google.com` is the domain name that Google's own corporate mail accounts use. The SPF record there exists for the purpose of showing recipients which servers are allowed to send mail addressed from `@google.com`.

Now, it just so happens that Google uses the same (or at least closely related) mail infrastructure for their corporate mail solution as is used for customers, so their `google.com` SPF record refers to `include:_spf.google.com`, just as they ask their customers to set up their SPF.

In practice, right now, `include:google.com` would just be a less efficient way of getting the `_spf.google.com` SPF referenced (it wastes one of your allotted 10 allowed indirections for no benefit), BUT it also ties your mail solution to  Google's corporate mail environment, which may or may not continue to be the same thing as Google customer mail environment in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The SPF record of `google.com` is:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

So, yes, technically you can replace it. You will however gain nothing, instead one more lookup will be used by the client. And the limit is 10.

For `sendpulse.com` the SPF record includes `mxsmtp.sendpulse.com` as well, but even more other domains that are most probably not relevant for you. This adds even more unnecessary lookups and is not desirable.

I would not recommend it.

Comment: Indeed, one would unnecessarily throw away one of the allotted 10 lookups *and*, just as importantly imo, insert a completely unnecessary dependency that outbound mail servers of Google's own corporate mail solution matches the mail servers used by their mail customers.